# Nginx Laravel GET request doesn't send array

Tags: laravel, apache, nginx, get

I'm using Laravel with NGINX and I can't recieve GET requests for some reason. They work perfectly with Apache (XAMPP).

This is my URL with parameters that I want to pass:

```
/table-search-client?model=Client&column=name&search=UAB
```

In my controller for this example I used dd() to just display the passed in array. This is what I get with **Apache** (correct):

```
array:3 [
  "model" => "Client"
  "column" => "name"
  "search" => "UAB"
]
```

This is what I get with **Nginx** (incorrect):

```
array:1 [
  "query_string" => null
]
```

Post method works perfectly, but I want to use Laravel's pagination and, with my understanding, that requires GET method.

I assume this is some sort of configuration problem, but I don't know what and where to edit in the Nginx config files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find the problem in the NGINX config file which is located in `etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

My previous configuration was like this:

```
location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
    }
```

So fore some reason while installing Nginx the $ sign was missed. So I only had to add it before `query_string`, restart Nginx and everything started working. So the final config looked like so:

```
location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```